# Trying to grab a convert a session variable to a string in a aspx. class file

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
string email = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["email"].ToString();
```

I am trying to do something like the code ab where i can retrieve the value stored inside of my session. I have already done `string email = (string)(Session["email"]);` on my aspx.cs files and it did return me the email stored in the session.

I am just now wondering how it can be done on class file.

This doesn't work

```
public int countBasketItems()
{

    int counter = 0;

    String CS = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(CS))
    {
        string email = HttpContext.Current.Session["email"].ToString();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Count(*) from basket where email = '" + email + "')", con);
        con.Open();
        counter = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    }
    return counter;

}
```

This works

```
   public int countBasketItems()
{

    int counter = 0;
    string email="";

    String CS = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(CS))
    {
        email = (string) HttpContext.Current.Session["email"];
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Count(*) from basket where email = '" + email + "'", con);
        con.Open();
        counter = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    }
    return counter;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method you are using should work.
Within the class file ensure you are importing System.web
Then in your class you should now be able to access HttpContext and thus the current session (httpcontext.current.session).

I use this method myself in web applications without fault.
I have class files that use that exact method without fault even cross project within the same solution.

Comment: this is the error>> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Questions should be asked as a comment, not posted as an answer. If you don't have enough rep to post a comment then please go ask/answer some questions until you do.

Comment: Can you post code from the class file for review please also can you show the method your using the call the class files function as to me that sounds like your not importing system.web into the class file which means that you dont have access to the httpcontext.
@Equalsk - sorry I will edit my answer to be an answer guess bad phrasing.

Comment: i have edited my question and provided the full method. I have also namespaced system.web

Comment: I'm assuming you have tried explicitly accessing in your class? e.g.
string email = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["email"].ToString(); as the code you posted doesnt show that your importing system.web in the class file once again leading back to my original answer.

Comment: i have solved it, i will add the code to edit so you can see.

Comment: Ahh the string was not defined correctly, please could you also add the import statement at the top of your corrected code for future people having the issue as the code in its current state will lead people to believe they do not require the import to make this methodology work where as that is not the case.